# Administrator cannot access files uploaded by IUSR on Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008

After moving our site to a new Windows Server 2008 box it's finally all working apart from one niggly problem.

When someone uploads a file the script creates a folder for it and saves the file to the new folder.

However, although I can download the file over the web, when I go into remote desktop as Administrator I can see the folder, but cannot open it or see the files contained within.

IUSR is the owner of the file, but the security tab doesn't give me the option to add a user.

Any idea what I've done wrong in the setup?

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that the scripts are explicitly defining the incorrect permissions and/or the permissions on the folder in question aren't set to be applied to child objects.  (Or UAC.  Almost anything can be  messed up if UAC's running and you're not mindful of it.)

Regardless, you don't get an `Add...` option on the security tab.  You need to either use `Edit...` to open the `Permissions` dialogue (and use the `Add...` option from there) or use the `Advanced` button to change ownership and/or Administrator permissions.  You should notice that if you use the `Advanced` button, then `Change Permissions...`, and then use `Add...` or `Edit...`, you have the option to change what the permissions apply to.  (`This folder only`, `This folder, subfolder and files`, etc.)

And of course, if UAC is enabled on the server, make sure that Explorer is running elevated, or you'll have normal user permissions, and probably won't be able to edit what you want to edit.